# automatic execution upon opening TexShop

Tags: texshop

I'm launching TexShop table from a statistical package. However upon launching I want it to typeset automatically to see the PDF. Now it opens the tex-file and I still have to press the typeset button to see the PDF. Is there a way to execute TexShop files upon opening a tex-file? I'm using Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, you just want to use TeXShop to compile your document and open it afterwards, automatically. So your are not using TeXShop as an editor.

If so, you could try to change the command in your statistics package to use `pdflatex` on the commandline instead of opening TeXShop.

Because I have no idea which statistics package your are using, I'm going to explain using `pdflatex` on the commandline in general: Open your Terminal and navigate to your working directory using `cd <path to your dir>` and call `pdflatex` by simply typing:

```
pdflatex foo.tex && open foo.PDF
```

The first part `pdflatex foo.tex` will compile your tex-file called 'foo.tex' and the second part of the given command `&& open foo.PDF` will open the output PDF-document after compiling was finshed.

You can also pass the path of your file directly to the provided code snippet, so you don't need to navigate to your directory by hand.

If you are not able to change the run command of your statistical package as needed, maybe you could use the commandline instead of the automatically executed run or think about a self-written shell script, which does the commandline stuff for you.

Comment: @user66806: I do not know 'STATA', so unfortunately I can't give you hints without knowing the used workflow. However, I'm using a Mac, too. So if you could describe how 'TeXShop' is run out of 'STATA' or what your current workflow is like, we propably could find a way solving your problem...

Comment: Thanks eventually the solution you gave was working!, The problem was that I had an underscore in my file name, (such as Tab1_cohrt1.tex). When I removed the underscore it worked!

Comment: And I had to use "shell /usr/texbin/pdflatex file.tex" instead of just "shell pdflatex file.tex". "shell" is a stata command, which launch external apps.